# :last-of-type when type is wrapped by another element

Tags: css

Lets say I have 3 fieldsets and I want 30px margin under all of them except the last fieldset.

```
.wrapper fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper fieldset:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  <fieldset>...</fieldset>
</div>
```

That's ok, but now what if my fieldsets are wrapped in an arbitrary element eg:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ANY>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  </ANY>

  <ANY>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
    <fieldset>...</fieldset>
  </ANY>
</div>
```

Now I have no margin on the first fieldset. I know why this happens, but I don't know a solution. Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: `any:last-of-type   fieldset:last-of-type` not working or not tested yet ? :)

Comment: @GCyrillus that would work if the `ANY` was consistent. Lets imagine this is angular and each `ANY` is a different directive.

Comment: okay so it could be  `:last-child  fieldset:last-of-type`  , i believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example. Need to take into account multiple elements, which is why the container of the fieldset needs to be taken into account.

```css
.wrapper fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper *:last-child fieldset:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <fieldset>#1 element</fieldset>
  </div>

  <div>
    <fieldset>#2 element</fieldset>
    <fieldset>#3 element</fieldset>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <fieldset>#4 element</fieldset>
    <fieldset>#5 element</fieldset>
  </footer>

  <div>
    <fieldset>#6 element</fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `only-child` selector. [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rewisaciko/edit?html,css,output)

```
.wrapper fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.wrapper fieldset:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.wrapper fieldset:only-child {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```